# Why are layers (or levels) fundamental means of organizing geographic data in almost all GIS?

Tags: layers, gis-principle

Layer (or levels) are a fundamental means of organizing geographic data in almost all GIS, why?

I am trying to understand the Layers in GIS been doing some research but am not getting the absolute answer of my question.

Comment: What would you see as an __alternative__ to layers?

Comment: If a map is thought of as an abstraction of reality, then we can more generally state the problem as: _Why are layers used so often as a means of managing abstraction_?  For example [Abstraction Layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) are often used in computer science.

Comment: Apparently some linguists also assume that layers (or levels in this case) are an intrinsic aspect of the process of abstraction.  See [Levels of Abstraction in Spoken and Written Language](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1460-2466.1967.tb01193.x/abstract).

Comment: @Simbamangu perhaps coverages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layers are used in GIS based on ease of use and data collection.  If you think about the way most data is collected, layers make sense.  Data is generally collected as a layer (i.e. a road survey collects data about roads, a vegetation survey collects data about vegetation).

Layers allow you to view data effectively.  Hypothetically, you could use an extremely detailed photograph as a map.  However, how are you going to pick out roads, rivers, and points of interest?  For this you need to be able to emphasize those aspects by distorting reality.  You need to thicken the lines for roads and rivers.  Editing single layers in order to achieve this is much easier than editing a complete composition.

Keeping data in separate layers also makes comparisons/interactions more simple.

Answer (score 1):

This is question for different forum because it sparks abstract discussion which contradicts the principles of stackexchange. However, as an enthusiast in GIs I will say this:

I think it has to do with the concept of looking at the world from above i.e 2D map view. Because GIS is abbreviation from Geographic Information Systems, it deals with different thematic layers that have information's distributed through specific geographical space. The only way to work with this data and try to combine it, manipulate with it and analyse it, is through layers (for now).

Maybe in near future we will have different options, who knows.

Answer (score -1):

Following the [ESRI Dictionary definition](http://support.esri.com/sitecore/content/support/Home/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/layer) of a layer, if you think of layers conceptually as legend items on a map, the organizational structure becomes apparent.

> [data structures] The visual representation of a geographic dataset in
>   any digital map environment. Conceptually, a layer is a slice or
>   stratum of the geographic reality in a particular area, and is more or
>   less equivalent to a legend item on a paper map. On a road map, for
>   example, roads, national parks, political boundaries, and rivers might
>   be considered different layers.

Answer (score -2):

layers are fundamental since

1. are easy to use and data collection.
2. layers allows viewing of data effectively.
3. layer in separate makes comparison more simple.